# Preserving a Month and Day as Date Format in Python Pandas

Tags: python, date, pandas

I'm trying to take a column in yyyy-mm-dd format and convert to it mm-dd format (or MON DD, that works too), while preserving a date or numeric format. I've tried to use pd.to_datetime, but it seems that doesn't work because it requires the year, so it ends up padding the new columns with year 1900. I'm not looking for conversion in which the new column is a object, because I need to use the column to plot later on. What's the best approach? Data frame is pretty small.

```
OldDate             NewDate1     NewDate2      NewDate3
2017-01-02          01-02        01/02         Jan 2
2015-05-14          05-14        05/14         May 14
```

Comment: You can't ditch the year and have a date format... as far as I know. Best you can do is a string

Comment: Ok, if that's true and I have a column of 01-01, 01-02, 01-03, etc. and they are strings, how can I make them a sequence so that they can be plotted on the x-axis? Why is something so conceptually simple made so difficult?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"OldDate":["2017-01-02","2015-05-14"]})

df  
    OldDate
0   2017-01-02
1   2015-05-14
```

Then you can do:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

df['OldDate']  = df.OldDate.apply(lambda s: dt.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d"))
df['NewDate1'] = df.OldDate.dt.strftime("%m-%d")
df['NewDate2'] = df.OldDate.dt.strftime("%m/%d")
df['NewDate3'] = df.OldDate.dt.strftime("%b %d")

df
    OldDate NewDate1    NewDate2    NewDate3
0   2017-01-02  01-02   01/02   Jan 02
1   2015-05-14  05-14   05/14   May 14
```

Comment: This would produce a string as well, which is what OP is trying to avoid

Comment: @PirateX Datetime representation is fixed for numpy/pandas. Use `strftime(format)` for non-conventional representations. As a downside, for non-conventional representations you would always have strings/object. If you have a different viewpoint, please share it with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substring concept on OldDate as below:

```
OldDate = '2017-01-02'

NewDate1=OldDate[5:]
print(NewDate1) # This will give result as : "01-02"

NewDate2 = OldDate[5:7] + "/" + OldDate[8:10]
print(NewDate2) # This will give result as "01/02"
```

Comment: This produces a string, which is what I'm trying to avoid.